# How to run and/or debug a large .NET Framework project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I have a large .NET Framework web project (many files and pages, it accesses SQL Server database) that I need to run, debug, and understand in Visual Studio 2015. I'm new to VS and the framework. I have a local repository of the code on my machine that's been mapped from a Team Foundation Server (TFS) using Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC).Do I need to somehow build the local repository in VS?

(1) I tried to right click on the local workspace file that contains all of the site’s files, and then opening it with VS—this didn’t work because it default-opened VS 2017, not 2015 like I need, and there’s no ‘Open with’ option to select VS 2015. (2) I tried opening the site’s login page from the local workspace and then clicking the run button, but it asked me about some options that I didn’t understand. (3) I tried importing it into VS 2015 as a file or a solution/project but that didn’t work either.

Can I run the project from TFS's Source Control? Any resources or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: (1) I tried to right click on the local workspace file that contains all of the site’s files, and then opening it with VS—this didn’t work because it default-opened VS 2017, not 2015 like I need, and there’s no ‘Open with’ option to select VS 2015. (2) I tried opening the site’s login page from the local workspace and then clicking the run button, but it asked me about some options that I didn’t understand. (3) I tried importing it into VS 2015 as a file or a solution/project but that didn’t work either.

Comment: Edit your question to include such details please.

Comment: Did you open VS 2015 first and then tried opening this project by clicking `File-> open project or solution`?

Comment: Yes. I had VS 2015 open and the Source Control up with all of the source files/code from the TFS. I had a Windows File Explorer open with the file containing the local repository up (what I tried right clicking on) as well.

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask the team that gave you that *large .NET Framework web project* to tutor you on the basic use of TFS. Unfortunately, we're not the site to provide tutorials.

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m a team of one. There’s no one to explain the tools or organization of the site. I was simply handed the keys.

Answer (score -1):

Typically I open a solution that is in TFS from the Team Explorer view. If the solution is under TFS Git you will need to change your source  control to Git under options. To open the Team Explorer view open the VS version you want to use then go to Team -> Team Explorer. Once the Team Explorer pops up. Select Home at the top then select Source Control, that should open up your workplace if you already have it mapped correctly if not you will need to map your local workplace. I then drill down until I find the solution in the Source Control viewer and double click on the solution file. That will do two things: 1. It will open the solution in the current instance of VS and 2. It will check it out to edit. Also i think you can hold down shift and right click on the solution file in a File Explorer, this might show the open with command.